# How to get particular string in xml using python or perl etc

Tags: scripting, python, xml

from here i need to get (username) "pelech" alone this is just example in my xml file i have 1000 users.

```
<user>
    <login>pelech</login>
    <password>passwords are saved outside</password>
</user>
```

i tried following script but it doesn't working.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("users.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for app in root.findall('user'):
    for l in zip(app.iter('login')):
        print("%s" % (app.get('login')));
~
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are on Linux OS - simple [***xmlstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) solution:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//user/login" -n users.xml
```

Answer (score 4):

I use beautifulsoup to achieve this

If you install using pip, follow the following instruction

```
pip install bs4
```

You can test it out in python interactive shell

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
>>> content = """<user>
...     <login>pelech</login>
...     <password>passwords are saved outside</password>
... </user>"""
>>> soup = Soup(content, "html.parser")
>>> soup.find_all("login")
[<login>pelech</login>]
>>> soup.find("login").text
'pelech'
```

I uses the default html.parser. If you have difficulties in parsing it correctly, you may consider using lxml instead.

For completeness sake, you can just iterate through the list returned from `soup.find_all("login")`

```
>>> for login in soup.find_all("login"):
...   print(login.text)
... 
pelech
```

Alternatively, the pythonic way

```
>>> usernames = [login.text for login in soup.find_all("login")]
>>> usernames
['pelech']
```

For more details refer to https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 4):

I can only assume your XML is formatted in a similar way to

```
<users>
    <user>
    <login>pelech 1</login>
    <password>passwords are saved outside</password>
</user>
<user>
    <login>pelech 2</login>
    <password>passwords are saved outside</password>
</user>
```

You need to find your login tag first, then you need to be grabbing the text of that tag as it iterates inside your loop.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("users.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for app in root.findall('user'):
    for l in app.findall('login'):
       print("%s" % (l.text));
```

Using this XML as an example, this works fine for me.

Comment: Would https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example xpath expressions make this more concise?

Answer (score 1):

If your file is guaranteed to be in this format with the login name inside the tags in a separate line, you don't need xml libraries and can do a simple

```
sed -n 's_ *</*login>__gp' your.xml
```

This removes the tags and leading spaces from that line and prints the remains (the user name!), while all other line are suppressed by the `-n` option.

Answer (score 0):

use lxml module

```
<user>
    <login>pelech</login>
    <password>passwords are saved outside</password>
</user>
```

The following code will extract pelech from the xml

```
from lxml import etree

document = etree.parse(open("users.xml"))
user = etree.xpath("//login")[0].text    #user will have value pelech
```

learn more about [xpath](https://www.javatpoint.com/xpath-expression) and [lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html)